# How can I open a call pickup screen when the app is in background without context in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

When my app is in the background a particular screen is not opening without context.
Here is my code to open a screen when clicking on the button of a notification:

```
void notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
  try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
    Map payload = json.decode(notificationResponse
        .payload!); // ignore: avoid_print print('notification(${notificationResponse.id}) action tapped: ' '${notificationResponse.actionId} with' ' payload: ${json.decode(notificationResponse.payload ?? "")}'); if (notificationResponse.actionId == 'Accept') { log("Call Accepted");

    ///tried [not working, currentState getting null ] 
    navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(Routes.CALL_PICKUP_SCREEN, arguments: {"userData": payload["userData"], "callId": payload["callId"]});

    ///tried [not working without context] 
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Routes.CALL_PICKUP_SCREEN, arguments: {"userData": payload["userData"), "callId": payload["callId"]});

    ///tried [not working] 
    navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(Routes.CALL_PICKUP_SCREEN, arguments: {"userData": payload["userData"], "callId": payload["callId"]});

    ///also tried getx 
    Get.to(() => AudioCallView(), arguments: {"userData": json.decode(remoteMessage.data["userData"]), "callId": remoteMessage.data["callId"]});

    ///also tried method channel 
    await const MethodChannel('android_channel').invokeMethod("openCallPickUpScreen", {'userData': userData.toMap(), 'callId': callId});
  } else if (notificationResponse.actionId == 'Reject') { log("Call Rejected");

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().
  cancel(1);
  // Dismiss the notification 
  } else {
  // other action 
  }} catch (
error) { log("error on notification tap in background : $error"); } }
```

How can I resolve this and open a particular screen from the background when clicking a notification button?
I want to show a call pickup screen when the app is in the background and the notification renders, like WhatsApp, Instagram, or a simple phone call from background.